# Inheritance, deriving from a derived class

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to create a class from a class that is already derived from another class. (bit confusing) It adds one extra attribute in the newest "PricedApt" class that is "price". The desired constructor call is as follows

```
   PricedApt p = new PricedApt("jill", 900, true, "jack", 1050.00);
```

The class is missing its constructor and im trying to create it but not sure whats wrong.

This is the (already derived (2nd) class)

```
public class RentalApt extends Apartment{

      private String tenant;
      private boolean rented;

      public RentalApt(String owner, int size, boolean rented, String who){
        super(owner,size);
        tenant = who;
        this.rented = rented;
      }
```

My code for the (3rd) class that I have attempted is

```
public class PricedApt extends RentalApt {

private double price;

public PricedApt(String owner, int size, boolean rented, String who, double priceTag) {
  super(owner,size,who);
  price = priceTag;
}

}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing incorrectly? The compilation error I'm receiving is cannot find symbol (line 2 column 3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For one, RentalApt has a four-argument constructor, but its subclass PricedApt is calling super() with only three arguments.

Try changing

```
super(owner,size,who);
```

to:

```
super(owner,size,rented,who);
```

Comment: Ah i totally missed that somehow.. Feel pretty silly. Thanks alot!

Comment: It happens to all of us. :)